# "Permission denied" while trying to find files

Tags: command-line, permissions, 20.04, find

I'm running:

```
sudo find / -name .mysql_history
```

and I'm getting:

```
find: ‘/run/user/999/doc’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/user/999/gvfs’: Permission denied
```

Why? Any help would be appreciated.

OS Name: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: Probably because you don't have read permissions on those directories?

Comment: @Sebastian, I'm executing the `find` command as root (`sudo`), which gives me also the `read permission` on those directories, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Have you checked what permissions/owner these directories have? Also, do you know who user 999 is? The first user on a system usually starts at 1000, so this looks a little weird.